# Layout contents are not showing

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

- I am using Android Studio 3.1.4.
- While Relative Layout is working fine but whenever I try creating the new project with floating action button the contents of the main layout are not visible in the preview window.
- Also if I chose default AppTheme then nothing shows up.
- In below images I am using the Material Dark theme which most of the time resolves the hidden widgets problem but when I tried using constraint layout with fab nothing is showing up.
- Gradle build is showing no problem too.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**As seen in the given picture, the contents of the layout are not showing:**

[image: As seen in the given picture, the contents of the layout are not showing]

**Errors which I am getting:**

[image: Errors which I am getting]

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".NoteActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_note">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_courses"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text_not_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Note title"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/spinner_courses"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/spinner_courses"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner_courses" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text_note_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Note text"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/text_not_title"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text_not_title"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_not_title" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Will it open source app? :P

Comment: gotta stackoverflow GitHub repo :P

Comment: hehe, great! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Edited the build.gradle like given below:

Changed `compileSdkVersion` from 28 to 27 and also target sdk to 27.

In dependencies changed these following too:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by adding the following packages on Gradle (and downgrading from 28.0.0);

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

This would mean changing the target and compile SDK versions too. You can change it back later after development is complete. 
Regards.

Answer (score -1):

All of your child item's layout_width are 0dp. Either give it a static value or use wrap_content accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for reply, added layout xml in question.

Comment: Since, it is ConstraintLayout, using "0dp" as width or height is absolutely normal.

Comment: Sorry didn't know you could do that. I think you are missing the dependency in the app level gradle file. Go ahead and add implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'